# how to use admin panel after upload project on server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, umbraco7

I am new to umbraco development. In one of my projects I have used Umbraco with ASP.NET MVC.

After publishing & uploading the project on a server, how do I access the Umbraco admin section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the back office of the site, go to http://[YOUR LIVE DOMAIN HERE]/umbraco/.

You were asked for a username and password when you set up the Umbraco site, you'll need to use that to access the CMS.